# What's this.$eval in Vue doing?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm migrating an old script which I didn't write from version 0.11 to 2.5.4 and I'm getting a warning saying :

> Replace this.$eval('reportData | reportFilter false') with a solution using normal JavaScript
>     Line 327: assets/js/custom-reports.js
>     Reason: vm.$eval has been removed, as it has no real use
>     More info: http://vuejs.org/guide/migration.html#vm-eval

I can see in the code its setting these values:

```
this.$set('reportData[' + key + '].selected', !selectAll);
```

And using them here:

```
var data = this.$eval('reportData | reportFilter false');
```

Has anyone got any idea whats going on here and how I can rewrite this to work in a new way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it is filtering `reportData` with a filter called `reportFilter` which I'm guessing is being passed `false` as a parameter. Filters in `Vue 2` don't work the same way, so you will need to move `reportFilter` to a method, however, if this is being used across multiple components you will probably want to create a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html), so:

```
// Filters mixin
const Filters = {
  methods:{
    reportFilter(data, flag){
      // reportFilter method
    }
  }

}
```

Then in any components where `reportFilter` is being used you will want to use the mixin:

```
new Vue({
  // ...
  mixins: [Filters],
  // ...
})
```

You can then change your `$eval` code to:

```
var data = this.reportFilter(reportData, false);
```

Here's a JSFiddle to give you an idea of how that works: https://jsfiddle.net/4b8vqccs/

Comment: Thanks, Craig! I will give that a go.